# If $c_1,c_2$ are scalars, and $A,B$ are invertible matrices, is there a way to solve $(I-c_1A)^{-1} = (I-c_2B)^{-1}$ for $c_1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $0\leq c_1,c_2 \leq 1$ are scalars, and $A,B$ are invertible matrices, with $I$ being the identity matrix. Then, suppose that we are given $c_2, A,B$ and we are trying to solve for $c_1$. In other words, how can we solve for $c_1$ in:

$$
(I-c_1A)^{-1} = (I-c_2B)^{-1}
$$
?

Would the following be valid?

\begin{align}
(I-c_1A)^{-1} &= (I-c_2B)^{-1} \\
 (I-c_1A) &= (I-c_2B) \\
 -c_1A &= -c_2B \\
 c_1 I&= c_2BA^{-1}
\end{align}

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are valid.

For it to have a solution, $BA^{-1}$ has to be a multiple of identity matrix.

$$BA^{-1} = qI$$

$$B=qA$$

Hence $B$ must be a multiple of $A$.

If $B=qA$, then $c_1 = c_2 q$.

Comment: If $BA^{-1}$ is not a multiple of the identity matrix, do there exist least-squares type solutions to the $c_1$ that best fits?

Comment: what is your objective function in this case? Frobenius norm? $2$-norm?  $\| (I-c_1A)^{-1} - (I-c_2B)^{-1}\|_F$? $\|c_1 I - c_2 BA^{-1}\|_F$?

Comment: Are these both equivalent? Or are they different? I am trying to approximate what $c_1$ should be, do you have any ideas what it would look like?

Comment: I believe they are different though I don't have a proof. you have to address the question of given two $c_1$, how do you measure which $c_1$ is better. The optimization of $\|c_1I-c_2BA^{-1}\|_F$ is just  a least square problem.